# How to open file in GUI mode with terminal?

Tags: gui

I could not find the section as you can open the file in a graphics mode, that is such a file 1.txt terminal displays the contents but I would love to see it with the gedit or another text editor?

Comment: How do you open a file in the terminal?

Comment: simply `gnome-text-editor "<filename>"`

Comment: Unclear/misunderstanding that if you want to open file in terminal **or** launching gui app by command-line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by entering the program name before the file name.

So to open index.html with gedit from a terminal you would use :

```
gedit index.html
```

It should be noted that this will run from the terminal, if you want to separate it and continue using the terminal simply add an `&` after the command, for example :

```
gedit index.html &
```

Answer (score 5):

Opening a text file in a text editor is as simple as Fernhill Linux Project's answer.

For a more generic "open with default program" command you may type `xdg-open filename`.

A video file would open with your default video player, a text file with your default text editor, etc.

This has the added advantage that you may close the terminal window without closing the application.

Answer (score 0):

You would just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
<program_name>
or
sudo <program_name>
```

To open a .txt file using gedit from terminal, you would do

```
gedit <file_name>
```

Note: Make sure that the program that you're trying to open is in your path; otherwise you have to enter the complete path.